# Kazam microphone Unknown

Tags: 20.04, microphone, screencast, video-recording, kazam

[image: kazam no audio input]

Have anyone faced the same error?

[image: audio input sources]

None of the sources seems to be working. I even tried disconnecting Bluetooth & restarting the "Kazam" app.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just posting the fix here to avoid confusion in the thread.

**FIX :** Update the function "time.clock()" in pulseaudio.py file with "time.perf_counter()"

**File location :**  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/pulseaudio/pulseaudio.py

'**time.clock()**' is deprecated from Python V3.3 and removed from Python v3.8

**Documentaion:** : https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#time.clock

Comment: It works although there are about 6 instances to replace.

Comment: there were 8 for me

Comment: replace all the instance

Comment: Here is the one liner to fix it: `sudo sed -i 's/time.clock/time.perf_counter/g' /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/pulseaudio/pulseaudio.py`

Comment: Not working, version 1.4.5-2, Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 6):

If you've just upgraded to ubuntu 20.04, see solution at #8, #12 of https://bugs.launchpad.net/kazam/+bug/1875530

Comment: What about for a fresh install?

Comment: I replace time.lock with time.perf_counter in my py file, and compare that with the one attached in your link, identical. so it's the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am using manjaro, firstly I installed it by

```
yay -S kazam
```

microphone is undetecting

**FIX** : Update the function "time.clock()" in pulseaudio.py file with "time.perf_counter()"

**File_location**: /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kazam/pulseaudio/pulseaudio.py

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a lot.