# No speakers, no microphone, but headphones @Dell Lattitude E6530 (20.04)

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

This used to work @18.04 LTS but stopped working at some point, so I decided to head for the newer 20.04 LTS, but the problem persists.

What I tried:

1. reinstall alsa-base and pulseaudio https://superuser.com/questions/1451847/sound-stopped-working-ubuntu-18-04
2. rename alsa-base config https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1770429
3. remove pulse config [No sound in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS after upgrade from 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029403/no-sound-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-after-upgrade-from-16-04-lts)

None of these solutions work.

Interestingly if I run pavucontrol, while yt is playing a video, I can see an amplitude, but I can't hear a thing. If I connect headphones it works as expected.

The result of aplay -l:

```
Karte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], Gerät 0: 92HD93BXX Analog [92HD93BXX Analog]   
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1   
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0 
Karte 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], Gerät 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]   
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1   
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0 
Karte 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], Gerät 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]   
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1   
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0 
Karte 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], Gerät 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]   
   Sub-Geräte: 1/1   
   Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0 
Karte 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], Gerät 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]   
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1   
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
```

result of pactl list sinks:

```
Ziel #0
    Status: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
    Beschreibung: Eingebautes Tongerät Analog Stereo
    Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
    Abtastwert-Angabe: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
    Besitzer-Modul: 8
    Stumm: nein
    Lautstärke: front-left: 28568 /  44% / -21,64 dB,   front-right: 28568 /  44% / -21,64 dB
            Verteilung 0,00
    Basis-Lautstärke: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    Quellen-Monitor: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
    Latenz: 0 usec, eingestellt 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Eigenschaften:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "92HD93BXX Analog"
        alsa.id = "92HD93BXX Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7e30000 irq 37"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1e20"
        device.product.name = "7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Eingebautes Tongerät Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line-Ausgang (priority: 9000, not available)
        analog-output-speaker: Lautsprecher (priority: 10000, not available)
        analog-output-headphones: Kopfhörer (priority: 9900, available)
    Aktiver Port: analog-output-headphones
    Formate:
        pcm
```

Comment: Did you upgrade to 20.04 or was it a fresh install?

Comment: @rtaft It was a clean install.

Comment: I have an E6530 laying around.  When booting to the Ubuntu 20.04 Live image the speakers work fine.  Are you able to confirm that this is not a hardware issue?  I don't even see anything in the bios to disable the speaker.

Comment: @rtaft I don't know howto rule out a hardware issue. If I'm not mistaken there are two speakers and both don't work plus the build in microphone. Would be a strange coincidence, don't you think?

Comment: if the soundcard itself went bad, it would take out all of that.

Comment: @rtaft: That's impossible, because as I wrote I can hear sound with headphones.

Comment: what is the output for `sudo hdajacksensetest -a`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with 16.04 and started working with 20.04 after updating the BIOS. If you see HDMI sound devices appearing and disappearing then update your BIOS. Is very easy to update, you download the .exe file from the Dell website and you copy it to your EFI partition. I created a folder and copied it to `/boot/efi/EFI/Dell/Bios/` Then you boot and press the right key (F2 or F12) to stop the boot process and select BIOS upgrade that will allow you to chose the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when i upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. check your python version, if it is above Python v3.8 then some [time API](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#time.clock) methods are deprecated.
In the

**FIX** : Update the function "time.clock()" in pulseaudio.py file with "time.perf_counter()" in all the occurrences

please find related issue and solution in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1246151/1087660) thread for Kazam application

Comment: Mhh but what file should I change? I don't have a kazam application nor should it seem to be related to the general sound settings

Comment: If it started in Ubuntu 18 and you didn't manually upgrade python to 3.8 in Ubuntu 18 (which would have likely broken stuff) then this is not the issue.

Comment: If you are able to find pulseaudio.py file for you r audio device or application check if anywhere "time.clock()" is used

Answer (score 0):

To check if your system has access to HDMI open a terminal and execute:

`aplay -l`

This should give you a list like:

```
 card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 0: ALC1200 Analog [ALC1200 Analog]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: ALC1200 Digital [ALC1200 Digital]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 1: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 1: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
   Subdevices: 0/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 1: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 1: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

In your case I'd expect some HDMI devices. If these are not available, then it is a driver problem - pulseaudio needs the data from alsa, so if alsa can't see it, pulseaudio can't either.

If those devices exist, issue

```
pactl list sinks
```

in order to check out which devices will accept audio signals.
In such cases I usually rely on installing `pavucontrol` which is the UI friontend for pulseaudio.

There you can select the devices needed:

[image]

**EDIT**

After the OP posted the necessary output some hints:

1. alsa can see the cards. So they exist and could be used.
2. Pulseaudio does **NOT** recognize them.

This can be seen in the sinks lists as well as in pavucontrol. Still not clear if pulseaudio recognized the cards or not.
The output of

`pacmd list-cards`

would be helpful.

One way to test is to check all the cards (in case list-cards delivers something) by doing:

`speaker-test -D hw:HDMI,N -c 2 -r 48000`

If one of those tests work (iter thru all cards you have, c is the card number) try to connect it with pulseaudio (the output MUST be listed in the `pacmd list-cards` list:

`pacmd set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 output:hdmi-stereo-extra1`

Both commandlines are examples, just to give you the gist:
You need to test which cards are working, then you link the alsa information to the working/desired output of pulseaudio.

Comment: I added the output of your comments in my initial post. I'm not quite sure what to chose in pavucontrol, as there are only profiles for 'anolog stereo duplex', 'analog stereo output', 'analog stereo intput' and 'off'

Comment: You are correct. See my updated answer. (since I speak german, I could interpret your output)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

> sudo apt-get install rhythmbox clementine

or

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall rhythmbox clementine

then reboot, in case there is still no sound.

Comment: Still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing drivers for that? It happened to me on Debian.
Install the necesarry firmware. (e.g. package `firmware-realtek`).

Answer (score 0):

Please restart alsa driver

```
sudo alsactl -F restore
```

It might be the one of the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Run `hdajackretask` and select the codec at the top.  If you don't see the devices you are looking for, select `Show unconnected pins` in the options.  If you see the devices now, you should be able to select `Override` to enable them.  I had to do this to get the jacks working on my docking station.  You can press `Apply Now` to test it, and `Install boot override` to commit it.